# Send current page URL to popup form hidden field when form is loading from separate php file?

Tags: jquery

I'm using fancybox on WordPress to load a form from another template file. The page URL I need looks like `http://domain.com/blog/#panier`

My template file code is

```
<?php require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');?>
<style>
#header, #footer{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        jQuery('#header, #footer').css("display","none");
        });
</script>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="330" title="Enquire Form"]'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm using contact form 7 and loading the short code in the template file.

Another plugin i'm using take the current URL of the page and sets it as a hidden field but because the form is loading from a template file and isn't placed directly on the page the hidden field value is wrong

```
<div class="hidden" style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden-742" value="http://domain.com/blog/?p=29" class="wpcf7-hidden">
</div>
```

How can I get the current URL of the page when the link is clicked to open the form. Then pass that URL to the forms hidden field and set it as the value?

Thanks

Comment: So the workflow is: `1. Click an element.` -- `2. invoke the popup` -- `3. populate popup with form` -- `4. send window.location.href to a hidden input within the popup, and set the value equal to the window.location.href`. Is this all correct?

Comment: That's correct the `window.location.href` being the initial page with the link that opened the form.

Comment: is the popup a `modal display` or are you actually using `window.open`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.

We can access the callback of the completed fancybox load through the `onComplete` function of fancybox, at this point, we can then take the `window.location.href` and place it into the input field.

[Here's the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WW9DA/)

**Here's the standalone jQuery** ->

```
$('a').fancybox({
  'onComplete': function(){
     $('#popup input[name="name"]').val(window.location.href);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm not seeing the value of the input being set to the window.location.href. The output I need would contain this in the input tag `value="http://domain.com/blog/#panier"` being the window URL